# Changing a JLabel when a button is pressed

Tags: java, swing

```
if(e.getSource()== quater){
     totalTemp = Double.parseDouble(total.getText() + .25);
     String total2 = Double.toString(totalTemp);
     total.setText(total2);
}
```

I am trying to change the JLabel total to add 25 cents to it when the quater Button is pressed I keep getting these long errors and nothing happens.

Comment: LOL Really? You aren't going to show us the 'long errors'? If you can't figure it out looking at the errors, how are we supposed to without anything to go off of?

Comment: `totalTemp = Double.parseDouble(total.getText() )+ 0.25;` Parse before you add.

Comment: Have you created ActionListener object and added it to your Button object ?  If Yes then can you post more code where you are doing it ? It will be helpful for us to help you better.  If Not then do some research as how to do so and in case you still face issues then post the code here in your question.

Answer (score 1):

well, first, you are trying to add a double value to a String, Not gonna happen. What you need, based on your code, is this:

```
    if(e.getSource()== quarter){
        partialTemp = Double.parseDouble(total.getText());
        totalTemp = partialTemp + 0.25;
        String total2 = Double.toString(totalTemp);
        total.setText(total2);
    }
```

This will work, trust me, mi amigo

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting should be `NumberFormatException`. Try your code in this way.

```
if(evt.getSource()== quater){
 double totalTemp = Double.parseDouble(total.getText())+ .25;
 String total2 = Double.toString(totalTemp);
 total.setText(total2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this out. you will your answer

```
 totalTemp = (Double.parseDouble(total.getText()) + 00.25);
 total.setText(Double.toString(totalTemp));
```

Instead of

```
 totalTemp = Double.parseDouble(total.getText() + .25); //if getText() contains "abc" returns "abc.25"
```

if `total.getText() ="abc"` then this become `"abc.25"` which raise `NumberFormatException` .

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, you are appending a `double` to the end of a `String`. For example, if `total.getText()` returned "1.2", then `"1.2" + 0.25` would equal `"1.20.25"`, which cannot be parsed as a `double` and therefore the `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

You need to first parse the `String` and then add the `double`.

```
double totalTemp = Double.parseDouble(total.getText()) + 0.25;
```